# Use Left Join for show 3rd Week data wrong result

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, group-by

I have a lot of data in my DB. i'm use Mysql.

for this case, i try to show 3rd week data by using some query:

```
SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 3rd
FROM inspection_report
WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 15 AND 21
GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
```

but the result show as:

```
line        count
fa 01      0.0000
fa 01      0.0000
fa 02      0.0000
fa 02      0.0000
fa 03      0.0000
fa 03      0.0260
```

It makes the data show two times.Then i try this query:

```
SELECT id,A.Line,week3.3rd
FROM inspection_report AS A
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT Line, (SUM(S) + SUM(A) + SUM(B)*0.4 + SUM(C)*0.1)/COUNT(Serial_number) AS 3rd
    FROM inspection_report
    WHERE DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 15 AND 21
    GROUP BY Line, WEEK(Inspection_datetime), YEAR(Inspection_datetime)
    ) AS week3 USING (Line)
WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY Line
```

but the result show like:

```
line                  count
fa 01                0.0000
fa 02                0.0000
fa 03                0.0000    //must be 0.0260
```

how do i do to resolve this?
thank's

Comment: Can't you just remove the GROUP BY week and year from your first try? (Only group by Line).

Comment: Start by adding year as an output column to your first query - so you're clear about what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll only get one row per `Line` on the first query if the 15th of the month happens to be a Sunday (or Monday depending on your configuration). Otherwise, the 15th through the 21st will be on two different weeks according to the [`WEEK` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week). I don't think you need to group by the week, however.

Although it's not entirely clear what you want to do or what your data looks like, I think you should be ok grouping by year and possibly month.

Comment: for this case, i want to count data weekly. i have tried to group just in `Line`, but i get the data count all week in one year. not in current month.

Comment: @klox, Your use of `DAY(Inspection_datetime) BETWEEN 15 AND 21` in the where clause limits it to one week, but that definition of the third week and the `WEEK` function's definition of the nth week are different, so it is returning two different values for the days between 15 and 21 of a given month. If you want the current month only, though, then you need the `MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)` in your where clause.

Comment: @jswolf19: i use this method for each week. ex: `1st week(1 until 7), 2nd week(8-14), 3rd week(15-21), 4th week(22-28), 5th week(29-31).`

Comment: @klox, I guessed that much. The `WEEK` function uses a different method to calculate the week number in the year, but in any case, the week will start on a Sunday or Monday. If the 15th is neither a Sunday nor a Monday, this means that even if you narrow your select to the 15th-21st, you will still get two different values out of the `WEEK` function which will cause you to have two rows if it is used in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: So,what is the better way to count weekly data instead of my way? so i can count data in weekly correctly.

Comment: @klox, Your way is fine if it does what you (your customers) need it to do. You just need to be aware that your way is not the same way as the `WEEK` function's way, so grouping using the `WEEK` function will result in two rows per `Line` in roughly 6/7 of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this from query:

```
WHERE MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND YEAR(Inspection_datetime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

and then all can work normally.